# How correctly write Jest test for avoid act() warning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-test-renderer

useEffect usually use Promises for update state.

This updates cause long warning in jest: `Warning: An update to null inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).`

How correctly write Jest Test for such case?

live example, Reproducible Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-for-useeffect-with-promises-spieq?file=/index.test.js

index.test.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import { create, act } from "react-test-renderer";

it("works", () => {
  let root;
  act(() => {
    root = create(<Hello />);
  });

  // console.log("From test:", );
  let repr = JSON.stringify(root.toJSON());
  expect(repr).toBe('{"type":"span","props":{},"children":["Hello! "]}');
});
```

Hello.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve({}).then(() => setCount(4));
  }, []);

  return <span>Hello! {count}</span>;
};
```

[image]

Upd 1:

the same result for one of propasal:

[image]

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ***as a code snippet*** in your question for the relevant code you are working with. Links out to external resources tend to go dead after a while. The code should be included with your question here for future readers.

Comment: @DrewReese I attached the link to sandbox with full reproducing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to use [testing-library/react](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) which could be use smoothly with jest and provide [async methods](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet/#async)

Your test would become something like:

```js
import React from "react";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

it("works", () => {
   const { baseElement } = render(<Hello />);
   expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
});
```

**EDIT**: For sake of completeness, in your example you're trying to test whether or not an update in your component happened after an effect which is using a promise.

In order to *waitFor* something async you can use the method [findBy](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#findby-queries) (*findBy methods are a combination of getBy queries and waitFor.*)

```js
import React from "react";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import { render, findByText } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

it("works", async () => {
  const { baseElement } = render(<Hello />);
  expect(await findByText(baseElement, "Hello! 4")).toBeVisible();
});
```

Let's me explain, `import "@testing-library/jest-dom"` allows you to use the the method `toBeVisible`

So, this test is rendering a component Hello and then it's waiting (with default value, 1000ms) inside the baseElement (which is the component itself) looking for the text "Hello! 4", then if found it will return the found element, which we are going to test whether is it visibile or not.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the same result.
You can check in sandbox, and I add screenshot for your example.

Comment: @GulaevValentin I think the problem should be focused in `react-test-renderer` and `useEffect` + Promise. `@testing-library/react` will work, but that doesn't directly answer your question

Comment: @slideshowp2 if rewrite promises inside ```useEffect``` to ```async``` function it works without warning. But the question how correctly test promises style.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this sample works correct

```js
import React from "react";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

it("works", () => {
  render(<Hello />);
  return waitFor(() => screen.getByText("Hello! 4"));
  // expect(baseElement.toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: i have edited my answer in order to explain better what I wanted to suggest you

Comment: @FrancescoVattiato in general you are correct. I just avoid use `async` and `await` and write in Promise style.

Answer (score 0):

Using `react-test-renderer` I got the same problem and fixed it like this:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

// Note: import explicitly to use the types shiped with jest.
import {it} from '@jest/globals';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer, { act } from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', async () => {
  await act( () => {
   renderer.create(<App />);
  });
});
```

Essentially it is the auto-generated App.test.tsx file with its original content, but I have added

1. act() as suggested by the error message AND
2. async-await